# VBA to extract names from a list at random isn't working

Tags: vba, excel

I want to randomly extract 280 names from a list (dynamic range) of thousands of authors, then concatenate them into 1 string with each name separated by OR.

So far I'm stuck at the first part. When I run the following code, nothing happens. Can anyone explain why? Thanks.

```
Sub Authors()

Dim InputRange As Range
Dim AuthorCount As Long
Dim AuthorRange As Excel.Range

Set InputRange = Range("A:A")
AuthorCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(InputRange) - 1

Set AuthorRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet").Range("A2:A" & AuthorCount)

Const nItemsToPick As Long = 280

Dim Authorlist As Variant
Dim i As Long

ReDim Authorlist(1 To nItemsToPick)
For i = 1 To nItemsToPick
    Authorlist(i) = AuthorRange.Cells(Int(AuthorCount * Rnd + 1), 1)
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What you have can produce dupes, so you need to run a dictionary alongside to hold the numbers you've selected and repack if selected.  280 out of 280 can be slow narrowing down, the last few, but say 280 of 1000 should be fine

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? Authorlist is being populated but not used for anything. Putting `Debug.Print Join(Authorlist, "OR")` just before `End Sub` seems to print out what you want...

Comment: @bobajob Thanks. I'm new to VBA and finding the syntax very confusing, so not sure what i was expecting. Is it possible to put Authorlist back into the sheet using Join(Authorlist, "OR") ?

Answer (score 2):

Using the below code

```
Sub PickSample(intSampleSize As Integer, intPicks As Integer)
    Dim arr() As String
Dim intCounter As Integer

ReDim arr(intPicks)

For intCounter = 0 To UBound(arr)
    arr(intCounter) = CStr(Int((intSampleSize - (i - 1)) * Rnd + 1) + (i - 1))
Next intCounter

Debug.Print Join(arr(), ",")

End Sub
```

I ran this on the following, PickSample(10,5) and got the following, showing the duplicate possibilities, this will become less as the difference between picks and samples increases.

```
9,9,6,10,10,2
5,3,6,7,2,3
10,4,5,8,0,6
9,8,4,10,9,0
0,8,8,7,0,4
7,5,6,3,3,8
```

If your selection is 280, but the data set is only 300, dupes still arise

`PickSample 300,280 
228,**92**,248,216,269,66,**107**,166,**107**,61,174,189,41,18,190,252,192,127,56,149,292,231,114,145,164,202,11,194,270,102,35,128,232,**107**,124,225,131,216,152,52,83,26,294,85,186,**92**,256,96,239,52,90,21,148,136,179,9,95,40,98,228,188,290,249,166,182,57,271,95,180,179,230,215,206,228,77,165,153,170,84,125,105,292,156,175,139,9,113,41,196,46,59,112,28,185,211,132,126,101,210,64,13,266,13,138,222,227,247,63,141,261,249,123,139,105,75,242,163,162,188,26,214,77,17,82,289,98,194,109,111,98,64,63,127,185,72,206,177,181,23,13,46,74,120,175,86,251,270,158,116,0,75,49,194,295,93,72,264,39,171,182,183,208,255,29,118,247,80,204,119,251,130,251,65,220,270,65,295,290,262,157,195,137,47,193,184,257,110,15,152,16,112,135,89,291,3,195,184,160,8,215,94,295,87,109,96,106,70,178,211,80,173,173,298,280,75,243,231,122,189,148,150,40,291,53,177,205,32,195,222,234,129,24,150,172,17,124,35,43,94,298,181,82,125,141,19,137,131,284,82,52,152,103,154,119,78,20,192,109,164,265,127,178,114,17,32,43,43,228,79,41,12,208,254,155,240,296,157,20,188,99,83
4,50,49,153,122,31,83,193,255,149,56,269,112,97,232,65,134,71,264,183,112,117,259,176,280,155,99,261,77,78,53,104,0,223,253,83,211,121,244,223,131,23,123,102,213,93,240,45,178,287,73,282,34,296,190,180,271,173,73,258,22,132,228,73,113,119,158,81,174,63,23,269,33,196,271,69,285,254,132,148,231,251,115,58,98,124,45,186,29,61,208,151,55,298,141,1,128,86,226,268,247,53,32,3,45,113,56,294,262,175,219,43,77,8,249,235,238,100,135,167,241,169,61,62,109,172,103,158,128,172,15,164,62,289,280,298,252,123,242,297,77,52,209,5,102,208,33,33,87,120,168,93,88,243,93,113,120,253,123,218,198,122,286,194,155,67,175,225,137,272,85,200,267,84,110,4,88,296,229,174,182,80,152,238,258,28,163,125,22,135,210,150,122,284,296,178,160,185,26,55,85,5,45,126,165,168,235,12,122,17,93,181,155,179,99,273,231,173,129,220,49,17,73,228,286,103,205,238,10,239,145,62,181,273,284,196,4,199,290,2,287,22,88,175,243,12,16,169,94,124,153,220,135,97,22,123,172,229,174,196,243,125,239,217,208,219,57,232,21,74,286,246,66,55,71,278,77,77,215,200,232
209,294,73,160,32,300,203,4,173,30,31,240,85,13,89,114,90,285,294,120,83,48,49,194,123,124,214,98,190,62,55,175,24,137,272,78,236,114,87,276,190,188,128,29,168,209,275,251,6,163,275,129,204,151,154,139,106,121,81,16,73,294,18,117,109,147,46,142,77,189,163,47,282,197,152,117,32,235,138,226,179,250,5,63,22,31,99,38,0,161,197,163,249,24,57,204,136,107,45,212,279,159,26,228,120,139,148,62,99,28,177,51,279,29,133,82,262,225,82,202,77,27,9,97,237,89,70,144,76,102,13,145,62,260,177,227,279,99,163,24,190,123,289,34,277,186,104,44,144,66,299,39,8,103,164,277,162,122,255,248,202,217,300,102,149,124,209,53,127,163,245,162,128,153,68,186,147,204,266,111,91,88,45,159,67,175,109,263,143,57,205,224,184,235,48,243,60,287,19,18,238,114,139,35,34,52,14,215,160,168,65,140,224,226,120,271,224,26,191,214,4,129,120,82,296,241,209,125,221,83,107,130,284,36,194,104,31,55,23,130,288,163,148,292,65,114,119,84,151,41,155,290,167,273,197,132,208,19,227,210,149,46,67,98,236,15,155,227,241,97,292,242,203,272,263,125,37,287,239,209,120`

Using a dictionary to handle the dupes, using this code

```
Sub PickSample(intSampleSize As Integer, intPicks As Integer)

Dim dicPicked As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim arr() As String
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim intPicked As Integer
ReDim arr(intPicks)

For intCounter = 0 To UBound(arr)
RetryPick:
    intPicked = CStr(Int((intSampleSize - (i - 1)) * Rnd + 1) + (i - 1))
    If dicPicked.Exists(CStr(intPicked)) Then
        GoTo RetryPick
    Else
        dicPicked.Add CStr(intPicked), 1
        arr(intCounter) = intPicked
    End If
Next intCounter

Debug.Print Join(arr(), ",")

dicPicked.RemoveAll
Set dicPicked = Nothing

End Sub
```

Gives results, hopefully dupe free

`PickSample 300,280
203,125,69,114,26,208,39,219,36,174,220,113,24,74,104,282,128,112,223,205,200,147,44,143,152,162,157,300,70,54,108,177,13,276,153,91,7,168,89,145,127,12,16,257,187,229,61,213,117,214,254,171,59,242,23,51,224,52,185,165,193,189,21,296,63,173,160,280,190,232,235,141,256,56,87,98,32,5,267,195,77,120,197,82,288,68,57,136,132,182,122,15,47,48,261,96,110,258,49,105,155,86,186,97,225,80,264,140,11,46,199,230,275,19,34,83,222,66,116,294,298,259,292,271,272,84,115,101,124,43,183,71,289,291,25,188,55,158,150,216,243,92,58,0,290,148,255,149,250,167,27,233,228,265,9,299,65,283,62,88,207,240,109,179,161,178,268,278,175,139,237,234,169,297,269,281,184,262,270,164,202,279,253,295,196,212,8,274,159,75,172,163,130,38,154,73,99,247,249,263,273,67,40,20,221,138,14,33,218,286,227,251,94,166,209,156,211,37,137,90,131,111,107,2,215,85,146,100,293,204,231,285,79,53,126,60,239,260,248,78,4,217,29,64,121,226,201,210,45,206,134,17,1,192,246,3,35,191,236,93,28,41,244,287,129,277,142,118,6,81,18,135,181,241,180,103,50,252,31,95,30
44,278,132,10,232,56,146,193,284,276,236,155,79,117,102,61,119,200,229,131,138,133,235,173,204,34,7,98,3,202,167,143,130,30,126,206,13,262,221,166,174,298,111,116,39,288,263,76,47,170,89,268,154,253,52,91,217,148,12,22,83,33,77,264,85,214,55,127,279,251,101,86,230,35,172,59,198,62,286,296,220,29,191,242,271,5,54,84,297,158,38,270,231,107,95,110,57,129,9,273,53,269,68,4,234,228,211,207,70,153,151,194,179,128,169,63,142,109,145,58,186,24,245,60,87,0,17,246,225,222,218,184,258,26,161,226,247,31,144,178,223,122,88,124,137,210,293,94,99,213,190,281,80,72,104,40,6,123,290,259,254,45,78,66,227,289,261,141,65,135,8,274,69,257,203,168,196,42,248,67,73,125,37,11,287,181,92,291,238,108,212,1,118,28,216,244,164,249,240,150,46,74,277,36,189,188,255,224,195,260,15,175,267,280,49,180,27,165,50,113,243,201,237,149,205,156,199,292,136,48,71,75,285,41,81,239,209,185,266,160,176,152,171,163,100,2,32,183,16,97,19,294,187,20,282,272,157,182,121,140,106,112,265,295,51,21,256,64,241,114,162,90,252,115,25,82,103,23,299,120,197
57,241,105,1,247,289,284,72,89,68,101,225,295,242,290,5,291,217,267,87,62,80,24,106,103,38,285,197,286,300,151,222,219,254,201,113,195,245,243,15,179,98,145,192,74,118,142,109,70,58,11,4,154,277,129,115,250,202,293,163,181,168,288,268,281,112,79,49,60,175,236,23,266,186,59,167,190,187,41,228,174,157,48,231,165,253,227,171,66,176,135,238,120,258,19,110,194,164,131,296,91,206,159,255,8,189,124,148,114,13,75,121,95,272,119,214,50,117,279,213,205,133,96,196,137,173,246,218,233,77,27,264,141,184,193,263,102,83,244,210,78,127,36,63,188,42,0,152,198,271,169,298,207,111,3,158,182,282,30,226,199,17,273,297,191,166,46,144,252,55,25,26,200,86,162,237,211,299,212,287,161,12,40,45,69,216,54,125,71,47,132,93,22,20,76,126,51,262,107,229,234,257,2,39,278,235,84,37,280,208,153,251,67,136,104,28,221,149,248,276,170,140,14,269,180,16,108,34,94,43,92,52,204,65,134,85,183,7,146,143,97,270,64,259,139,160,260,223,32,81,177,33,178,185,90,292,9,232,209,265,10,88,283,147,123,99,261,240,6,138,274,122,61,203,249,155,256,44,294,116,35`

Answer (score 1):

this function picks `nItemsToPick` random elements up from `arr` array and returns them into an array:

```
Function PickNRandomElementsFromArray(arr As Variant, nItemsToPick As Long) As Variant
    Dim arrSize As Long
    Dim i As Long, iPick As Long
    Dim temp As String

    arrSize = UBound(arr) '<--| count the values as the array size
    If nItemsToPick > arrSize Then nItemsToPick = arrSize '<--| the items to be picked cannot exceed array size
    For i = 1 To nItemsToPick
        iPick = Int((arrSize - (i - 1)) * Rnd + 1) + (i - 1) '<--| pick a random number between 'i' and 'arrSize'

        ' swap array elements in slots 'i' and 'iPick'
        temp = arr(iPick)
        arr(iPick) = arr(i)
        arr(i) = temp
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve arr(1 To nItemsToPick) '<--| resize the array to first picked items
    PickNRandomElementsFromArray = arr '<--| return the array
End Function
```

which you can exploit as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Authors()
    Dim Authors As Variant, AuthorsList As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet") '<--| reference your relevant worksheet
        Authors = Application.Transpose(.Range("A2", .Cells(.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value) '<--| fill 'Authors' array with its column "A" values from row 2 down to its last not empty one
        AuthorsList = PickNRandomElementsFromArray(Authors, 280) '<--| fill 'AuthorsList' array with a selection of 280 random elements of 'Authors'
        .Range("B1").Value = Join(AuthorsList, " OR ") '<--| fill cell "B1" with a string build by concatenating 'AuthorsList' values delimited with " OR "
    End With
End Sub
```

that can be quite contracted (and made as much less readable) to:

```
Sub Authors()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet") '<--| reference your relevant worksheet
        .Range("B1").Value = Join(PickNRandomElementsFromArray(Application.Transpose(.Range("A2", .Cells(.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value), 280), " OR ")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Corrado_, did you get through it?

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, you seem to want to concatenate the array of strings, then put it back into excel. This, put just before the `End Sub`, will put it into cell B1 for example:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = Join(Authorlist, "OR")
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. I also want to loop this process for the entire author but I will have a go at this myself. Thanks again